# get user object from api after register or login

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, authentication, object

i have a big problem
i do a register and login form and i have the APIs, when the user login or register his email go to local storage, and all other info go to database with email , the problem:i want to get user object from api after logging in <
i did it by get the email from localstorage and find it in api , but it gives me undefined

```
export default function Projects() {
  const[data,setData] = useState([])
  const user= localStorage.getItem('email')
  const [userA, setUserA] = useState('')

  
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('email'))
  console.log(user)
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/show")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data.find(item => item.email !== user )))
    },[])


    const serviceItem = data.map((item) => 
      <Link to ={`/states/${item.id}`} className="col-md-6" >
      
        <div className="card">
          <video width="100%" autoPlay muted>
                <source src={`/uploads/${item.service_video}`} type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>
          <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card-text">{item.service_text_en}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </Link>
     )

  return (
    <div className="bg-custom">
      <div className="container" id="services">
        <h1 className="text-center fw-bold mb-4">Services</h1>
          <div className="row">
            { userA  ? serviceItem : <div className="text-center">You Are Not Accepted Yet</div>}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 );
}
```

i just want the object that the email in localstorage = it, the array of data :

```
0
: 
{id: 1, name: 'nageeb', email: 'fff@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-10T12:18:39.000000Z', …}
1
: 
{id: 2, name: 'very good', email: 'ce@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-10T12:22:10.000000Z', …}
2
: 
{id: 3, name: 'good', email: 'test@gmail.coms', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-10T13:27:26.000000Z', …}
3
: 
{id: 4, name: 'nageeb', email: 'test@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-11T16:19:55.000000Z', …}
4
: 
{id: 5, name: 'nageeb', email: 'ver@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-11T16:30:54.000000Z', …}
5
: 
{id: 6, name: 'nageeb', email: 'nice@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-11T16:32:33.000000Z', …}
6
: 
{id: 7, name: 'good', email: 'tsest@gmail.coms', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-11T16:33:31.000000Z', …}
7
: 
{id: 8, name: 'nageeb', email: 'nag@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, created_at: '2022-09-11T16:55:49.000000Z', …}
length
: 
8
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

Comment: You never call `setUserA`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user in useEffect dependency array. Let me know if it works.

```
useEffect(()=>{
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/show")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.find(item => item.email === user )))
},[user])
```

Comment: no it dosn't work

Comment: Do you get user detail in this log console.log(user) ?

Comment: If its ok can I get the response object and user data you are getting

Comment: in console.log(user) the result is "nag@gmail.com" , in api there are 8 objects in array , the last one have the same email in email key

Comment: can you give me dummy data of your array with only one element

Comment: and also do you log the user before calling the api inside the useEffect just to check if you are getting data their or not

Comment: accepted: 0
created_at: "2022-09-11T16:55:49.000000Z"
email: "nag@gmail.com"
email_verified_at: nullid
: 
8
name
: 
"nageeb"
updated_at
: 
"2022-09-11T16:55:49.000000Z"
user_type
: 
"member"

Comment: that's the last object

Comment: i log the user before getting data

Comment: ohh I am sorry bud I am updating my answer actually the condition is wrong

Comment: it should be ===

Comment: i knew it after posting the question , but it still undefined , but there is someting weird ,
when the condition !== it gives me the first object

Comment: ohh man its really annoying

Comment: thank you for helping me man , but please if you find any solution tell me

Comment: give me whole array and change the data let me try on my side

Comment: one thing more try to change then(dataRes => console.log(dataRes.find(item => item.email === user ))

Comment: Please try this and update me if its works

Comment: i changed it but nothing happend , i edit my question and add the whole array